# How to avoid to save exponation value in SQL Server from controller

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am saving large value in a SQL Server column from my controller. But the value is saved in the exponentiation form like `3.3733E+15`. Actual value is 16 digit no.

But when I access the value I get an error. Any way to save value in 16 digits in SQL Server E.g.: `2016100100123401`.

Comment: That isn't a datetime value is it? 01/10/2016 00:12:34.01 etc?

Comment: What error do you get when try to get the exponential value?

Comment: Use type BigInt

Comment: What is the data type of your SQL Server column where you are trying to save large 16 digit number?

Comment: data type of your SQL Server column is float. And perform calculation on this column.